# Recursively flattening subdirectories in a root directory and maintaining level 1 sub-directory structure

Tags: shell, file, terminal, directory, subdirectory

I have a large n-level directory structured as follows:

```
root
  |
   subdir1
      |
       sub_subdir1
           |
            ....(n-2 levels).....
                                 |
                                  file1
  |
   subdir2
      |
       sub_subdir2
           |
            ....(n-2 levels).....
                                 |
                                  file2
```

I want to flatten the directory so that all level 1 **subdirs** contain **files**. I also want to remove the level 2 to (n-1) **sub_subdirs** as they contain no files.

**Desired Result**

```
root
  |
   subdir1
      |
       file1
  |
   subdir2
      |
       file2
```

I have found a lot of posts explaining methods to *flatten* directories but none that explains how to do this in a controlled manner, i.e.,

- by specifying the levels to be flattened
- or doing it recursively for all sub_directories in a root directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same on stackexchange Unix & Linux and got two comprehensive solutions. Here is the link - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531929/recursively-flattening-subdirectories-in-a-root-directory-and-maintaining-level/531937?noredirect=1#comment984926_531937